# SQL condition based on a select subquery column

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

Using MSSQL, I want to apply a condition based on a select subquery. How can I do it optimally ?

Here is my initial query

```
SELECT tblA.Col, tblB.firstdate, tblC.CCol
FROM tblA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 t.PlacementDate firstdate
             FROM ( SELECT PlacementDate from TAB1 WHERE TAB1.Col3 = tblA.ACol UNION SELECT PlacementDate FROM TAB2 WHERE TAB2.Col3 = tblA.ACol) t 
             ORDER BY PlacementDate) tblB
INNER JOIN tblC on tblC.ColNameC = tblA.ColNameA
```

And I want to add WHERE condition using table `t` ( UNION result ) in order to select today's data :

```
WHERE CAST(t.PlacementDate AS DATE) = CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
```

So the final code is :

```
SELECT tblA.Col, tblB.firstdate, tblC.CCol
FROM tblA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 t.PlacementDate firstdate
             FROM ( SELECT PlacementDate from TAB1 WHERE TAB1.Col3 = tblA.ACol UNION SELECT PlacementDate FROM TAB2 WHERE TAB2.Col3 = tblA.ACol) t 
             ORDER BY PlacementDate) tblB
INNER JOIN tblC on tblC.ColNameC = tblA.ColNameA
WHERE CAST(t.PlacementDate AS DATE) = CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
```

But I can't reference the column `PlacementDate` from `t` and I have this error message appearing :

```
The multi part identifier 't.PlacementDate' could not be bound
```

Comment: please add your where condition in your code my be you place wrong place update your question for more info.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `tblB.PlacementDate` not `t.PlacementDate`. By the way, casting to date is probably not the best way to do this, probably better to do `WHERE tblB.PlacementDate >= CAST(CAST(getdate() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) AND tblB.PlacementDate < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)`

Comment: Following your suggestion, when replacing `tblB.PlacementDate` instead, it will base the WHERE clause on `firstdate` from table `s` : where `firstdate = today's date`. However, that is not what I'm searching for : I want to select the firstdate (ok) and have condition where data placement data is today (nok).

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT tblA.Col, tblB.PlacementDate, tblC.CCol
FROM tblA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 PlacementDate 
             FROM 
             ( SELECT PlacementDate from TAB1 WHERE TAB1.Col3 = tblA.ACol 
               UNION 
               SELECT PlacementDate FROM TAB2 WHERE TAB2.Col3 = tblA.ACol
             ) t 
             WHERE CAST(t.PlacementDate AS DATE) = CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
             ORDER BY PlacementDate) tblB
INNER JOIN tblC on tblC.ColNameC = tblA.ColNameA
```

Comment: This will select `TOP 1 PlacementDate` for today's date. I wanted to select this seperatly from the condition so I can select Top 1 of PlacementDate and also use it independantly in the WHERE clause to retrieve the data for events placed today.

Comment: as you wish if you go on with `where` condition then remove top 1 from the select statement.

Comment: But I want to use `TOP 1 PlacementDate` for a matter. The goal is to use the column in both placements ( select and where ).

Comment: then what is the problem you face ?

Comment: The problem is not abling to apply the where clause because the column PlacementDate is not bound from table t.